# Unable to link CSS to website after Deployment

Tags: html, css, web, path, host

I bought a template online, and edited some of the HTML. I use x10Hosting for free server and domain name. The website is deployed;

http://www.wizerwish.x10host.com

However, the CSS is not recognised or executed no matter what path I write in the index.html file.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Unishop | Universal E-Commerce Template
    </title>
    <!-- SEO Meta Tags-->
    <meta name="description" content="Unishop - Universal E-Commerce Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="shop, e-commerce, modern, flat style, responsive, online store, business, mobile, blog, bootstrap 4, html5, css3, jquery, js, gallery, slider, touch, creative, clean">
    <meta name="author" content="Rokaux">
    <!-- Mobile Specific Meta Tag-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <!-- Favicon and Apple Icons-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
    <!-- Vendor Styles including: Bootstrap, Font Icons, Plugins, etc.-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/vendor.min.css">




              <!-- THIS IS WHERE THE CSS FILES ARE -->






  <link id="mainStyles" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" 
            href="css/styles.min.css">
            <link id="mainStyles" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" 
            href="css/styles.css">
            <!-- Modernizr-->
            <script src="js/modernizr.min.js"></script>
          </head>
```

That is the html. The CSS folder path is as follows, starting from the desktop;

template-1/dist/css/ 
NOTE: the template-1 folder is on the desktop.

I have even copied and pasted the CSS files in the same folder (dist) where the html and other file are. But it is still not working.

Comment: Can you show your folder structure?

Comment: Your CSS is included as `/css/vendor.min.css`. I could reach your file trough `http://www.wizerwish.x10host.com/vendor.min.css`. I believe you can remove `/css` from your includes, or move the files into the folder.

Comment: Instead of using your locally saved CSS files, change it to the online version of the URL that contains the demo of your template for you to be sure something is not actually broken in the HTML file.

Comment: From the URL. we could not found the right Path. Can you show your folder structure starts from Index file

Comment: https://imgur.com/disUlTG here is my folder structure/ path

Comment: @Govind my template-1 folder is on my desktop. Inside that folder, i have a folder called dist. Then in the dist folder, I have my html files, AND a folder called css which is where my css files are. 

To answer your question, yes. Technically I am trying to access the CSS files from my desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accessed your css file and got it working by removing the `css & js` path. all files are in same path. so no need of path extension.

[image]

Comment: I dont understand. I have done exactly what you did, yet my website still does not execute the CSS. I removed the css path also but it still wont execute. Thank you for your effort though

Comment: That's odd. Can you do it, and does it work, whilst using dev tools?

Comment: I made it work. By removing the css/ path I made it somewhat execute the CSS. At least I know I am on the right path since some sort of styling caught to the page. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome, glad you got it (partially) fixed :)